# How to add DOCTYPE in the target xml using xslt?

Tags: xslt

i want to transmit exactly the source xml into target xml with only addition of DOCTYPE in the target xml . 
My source XMl is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <ns0:mt_socreate_ob xmlns:ns0="http://socreate">
 <ZSPL00>
  <Empid>12</Empid> 
  <Firstname>latif</Firstname> 
  <Secondname>rahman</Secondname> 
  <Dept>tata</Dept> 
  </ZSPL00>
  </ns0:mt_socreate_ob>
```

---

Target XML should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

<!DOCTYPE ZSPL00 SYSTEM "sap2grips.dtd">

   <ns0:mt_socreate_ob xmlns:ns0="http://socreate">

    <ZSPL00>

     <Empid>12</Empid>

     <Firstname>latif</Firstname>

     <Secondname>rahman</Secondname>

      <Dept>tata</Dept>

  </ZSPL00>

  </ns0:mt_socreate_ob>
```

I am writing the following xslt code but not getting the desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" doctype-system="sap2grips.dtd"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Default: copy everything -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please correct my code to get the above result

Comment: Please post the result you get with your current XSLT.

Comment: result i m getting is:
   <mt_socreate_ob><ZSPL00>
        <Empid>12</Empid>
        <Firstname>latif</Firstname>
        <Secondname>rahman</Secondname>
        <Dept>tata</Dept>
    </ZSPL00>
</mt_socreate_ob>  i should get <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 

<!DOCTYPE ZSPL00 SYSTEM "sap2grips.dtd">
at the top

Answer (score 3):

**Any conforming XSLT processor will *not* generate semantically incorrect `DOCTYPE` declaration as the one you want is**.

You want:

```
<!DOCTYPE ZSPL00 SYSTEM "sap2grips.dtd">
```

and this is wrong, because `ZSPL00` isn't the name of the top element of the XML document (which really is `ns0:mt_socreate_ob`)

**According to the [W3C XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-doctypedecl)**:

```
[28] doctypedecl   ::=   '<!DOCTYPE' S Name (S ExternalID)? S? ('[' intSubset ']' S?)? '>'
```

where:

"*The* `Name` *in the document type declaration MUST match the element type of the root element*."