# Remove elements from XML based on condition

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fcpxml>

<fcpxml version="1.9">
    <resources>
        <format id="r1" name="FFVideoFormat1080p60.0" frameDuration="50/3000s" width="1920" height="1080" colorSpace="1-1-1 (Rec. 709)"/>
        <asset id="r2" name="1x.mp4" start="0s" hasVideo="1" format="r1" hasAudio="1" audioSources="1" audioChannels="2" duration="1731150/3000s">
            <media-rep kind="original-media" src="file:///Users/shrikant/Desktop/1x.mp4"></media-rep>
        </asset>
    </resources>
    <library>
        <event name="auto-editor output">
            <project name="1x.mp4">
                <sequence format="r1" tcStart="0s" tcFormat="NDF" audioLayout="stereo" audioRate="48k">
                    <spine>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="0s" ref="r2" duration="1400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="1400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3250/3000s" start="41400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="4650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4300/3000s" start="74700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="8950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3850/3000s" start="105950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="12800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8250/3000s" start="124500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="21050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="148400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="24200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2150/3000s" start="155850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="26350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13700/3000s" start="158450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="40050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6950/3000s" start="189800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="47000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7500/3000s" start="197150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="54500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="205150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="54750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="219150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="58100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="229600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="58200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1500/3000s" start="230100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="59700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12950/3000s" start="235950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="72650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="22550/3000s" start="266300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="95200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3650/3000s" start="291050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="98850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3550/3000s" start="295150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="102400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4450/3000s" start="299350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="106850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="321300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="106950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6850/3000s" start="328050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="113800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="50/3000s" start="348850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="113850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10550/3000s" start="349650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="124400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13600/3000s" start="377400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="138000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6050/3000s" start="391400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="144050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="11100/3000s" start="397900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="155150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="409700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="155400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="414450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="158750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="11700/3000s" start="423850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="170450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4950/3000s" start="436550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="175400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="442100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="176550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1250/3000s" start="455950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="177800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="459500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="177950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2350/3000s" start="464050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="467350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="483300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13700/3000s" start="484450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="194350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1400/3000s" start="498800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="195750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14100/3000s" start="509000/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="209850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4350/3000s" start="523450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="214200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8400/3000s" start="529450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="222600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="900/3000s" start="539650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="223500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="50/3000s" start="570350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="223550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2050/3000s" start="575550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="225600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3700/3000s" start="585550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="229300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="596250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="232650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2350/3000s" start="606600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="235000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1650/3000s" start="609450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="236650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="611600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="236800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1550/3000s" start="627300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="238350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8550/3000s" start="636200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="246900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1050/3000s" start="651650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="247950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="658100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="248050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="674350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="248250/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3250/3000s" start="733400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="251500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2100/3000s" start="737350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="253600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="748100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="256750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1800/3000s" start="778500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="258550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14050/3000s" start="780650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="272600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="5250/3000s" start="795050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="277850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3300/3000s" start="801300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="281150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="819400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="282300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1450/3000s" start="835750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="283750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6450/3000s" start="838450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="290200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1200/3000s" start="845500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="291400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2950/3000s" start="851650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="294350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="16250/3000s" start="855200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="310600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="872250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="310800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3600/3000s" start="877500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="314400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4200/3000s" start="883250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="318600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="896750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="318800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="5700/3000s" start="902900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="324500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1450/3000s" start="909250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="325950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="923150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="329100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="933200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="329400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="979850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="330550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="985600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="330800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2700/3000s" start="1020700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="333500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="1027550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="333650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1250/3000s" start="1033100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="334900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1035900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="335150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1550/3000s" start="1146850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="336700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1151200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="336950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2250/3000s" start="1156600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="339200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12900/3000s" start="1161950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="352100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2650/3000s" start="1176250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="354750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="19450/3000s" start="1187800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="374200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1209600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="374450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="1217350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="377600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4450/3000s" start="1220950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="382050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="9050/3000s" start="1225800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="391100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1235700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="391350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13250/3000s" start="1247600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="404600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="1261700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="404900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7000/3000s" start="1417050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="411900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1600/3000s" start="1429900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="413500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="1446100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="413700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3750/3000s" start="1451900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="417450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1650/3000s" start="1492050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="419100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4900/3000s" start="1494300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="424000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="750/3000s" start="1500700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="424750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6100/3000s" start="1503700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="430850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="850/3000s" start="1510450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="431700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="16900/3000s" start="1514650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="448600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10600/3000s" start="1532100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="459200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6400/3000s" start="1543900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="465600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3850/3000s" start="1550800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="469450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4150/3000s" start="1555750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="473600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4150/3000s" start="1560750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="477750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2050/3000s" start="1565850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="479800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7050/3000s" start="1569750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="486850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14750/3000s" start="1612850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="501600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6850/3000s" start="1629100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="508450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3050/3000s" start="1636850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="511500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="1643300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="511800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1900/3000s" start="1665550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="513700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3900/3000s" start="1668800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="517600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10400/3000s" start="1679950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="528000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2500/3000s" start="1691000/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="530500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3500/3000s" start="1693800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="534000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12000/3000s" start="1697650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                    </spine>
                </sequence>
            </project>
        </event>
    </library>
</fcpxml>
```

I want to **delete all the "asset-clip" elements** which has **duration less than 1000**
so elements like this

```
<asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="54500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="205150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
```

has duration="250/3000s" and the value before "/" is 250 which is less than 1000 so the whole line will be deleted from my xml. Can some good soul guide me on this python code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about XSLT based solution?

Comment: yeah just the code should work from python

Comment: I am not familiar with XSLT can you write this for me

Comment: Please show your efforts; what exactly is the problem? With ElementTree, you can use the `remove()` method on `spine` to remove the `asset-clip` child elements that fulfil the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Here is XSLT based solution.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

One single line 2nd template is removing the `<asset-clip>` elements that have duration value before "/" less than 1000.

Useful link: [How to add DOCTYPE in the target xml using xslt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459881/how-to-add-doctype-in-the-target-xml-using-xslt)

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="asset-clip[number(substring-before(@duration, '/')) &lt; 1000]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

**ElementTree** based solution below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

MIN_SIZE = 1000

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fcpxml>

<fcpxml version="1.9">
    <resources>
        <format id="r1" name="FFVideoFormat1080p60.0" frameDuration="50/3000s" width="1920" height="1080" colorSpace="1-1-1 (Rec. 709)"/>
        <asset id="r2" name="1x.mp4" start="0s" hasVideo="1" format="r1" hasAudio="1" audioSources="1" audioChannels="2" duration="1731150/3000s">
            <media-rep kind="original-media" src="file:///Users/shrikant/Desktop/1x.mp4"></media-rep>
        </asset>
    </resources>
    <library>
        <event name="auto-editor output">
            <project name="1x.mp4">
                <sequence format="r1" tcStart="0s" tcFormat="NDF" audioLayout="stereo" audioRate="48k">
                    <spine>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="0s" ref="r2" duration="1400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="1400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3250/3000s" start="41400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="4650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4300/3000s" start="74700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="8950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3850/3000s" start="105950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="12800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8250/3000s" start="124500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="21050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="148400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="24200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2150/3000s" start="155850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="26350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13700/3000s" start="158450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="40050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6950/3000s" start="189800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="47000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7500/3000s" start="197150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="54500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="205150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="54750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="219150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="58100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="229600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="58200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1500/3000s" start="230100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="59700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12950/3000s" start="235950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="72650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="22550/3000s" start="266300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="95200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3650/3000s" start="291050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="98850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3550/3000s" start="295150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="102400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4450/3000s" start="299350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="106850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="321300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="106950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6850/3000s" start="328050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="113800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="50/3000s" start="348850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="113850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10550/3000s" start="349650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="124400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13600/3000s" start="377400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="138000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6050/3000s" start="391400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="144050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="11100/3000s" start="397900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="155150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="409700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="155400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="414450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="158750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="11700/3000s" start="423850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="170450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4950/3000s" start="436550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="175400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="442100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="176550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1250/3000s" start="455950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="177800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="459500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="177950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2350/3000s" start="464050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="467350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="483300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="180650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13700/3000s" start="484450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="194350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1400/3000s" start="498800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="195750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14100/3000s" start="509000/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="209850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4350/3000s" start="523450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="214200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8400/3000s" start="529450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="222600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="900/3000s" start="539650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="223500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="50/3000s" start="570350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="223550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2050/3000s" start="575550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="225600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3700/3000s" start="585550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="229300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3350/3000s" start="596250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="232650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2350/3000s" start="606600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="235000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1650/3000s" start="609450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="236650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="611600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="236800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1550/3000s" start="627300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="238350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="8550/3000s" start="636200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="246900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1050/3000s" start="651650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="247950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="100/3000s" start="658100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="248050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="674350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="248250/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3250/3000s" start="733400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="251500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2100/3000s" start="737350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="253600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="748100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="256750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1800/3000s" start="778500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="258550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14050/3000s" start="780650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="272600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="5250/3000s" start="795050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="277850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3300/3000s" start="801300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="281150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="819400/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="282300/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1450/3000s" start="835750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="283750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6450/3000s" start="838450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="290200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1200/3000s" start="845500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="291400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2950/3000s" start="851650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="294350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="16250/3000s" start="855200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="310600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="872250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="310800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3600/3000s" start="877500/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="314400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4200/3000s" start="883250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="318600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="896750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="318800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="5700/3000s" start="902900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="324500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1450/3000s" start="909250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="325950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="923150/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="329100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="933200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="329400/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1150/3000s" start="979850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="330550/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="985600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="330800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2700/3000s" start="1020700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="333500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="150/3000s" start="1027550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="333650/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1250/3000s" start="1033100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="334900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1035900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="335150/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1550/3000s" start="1146850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="336700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1151200/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="336950/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2250/3000s" start="1156600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="339200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12900/3000s" start="1161950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="352100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2650/3000s" start="1176250/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="354750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="19450/3000s" start="1187800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="374200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1209600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="374450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3150/3000s" start="1217350/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="377600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4450/3000s" start="1220950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="382050/3000s" ref="r2" duration="9050/3000s" start="1225800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="391100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="250/3000s" start="1235700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="391350/3000s" ref="r2" duration="13250/3000s" start="1247600/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="404600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="1261700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="404900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7000/3000s" start="1417050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="411900/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1600/3000s" start="1429900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="413500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="200/3000s" start="1446100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="413700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3750/3000s" start="1451900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="417450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1650/3000s" start="1492050/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="419100/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4900/3000s" start="1494300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="424000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="750/3000s" start="1500700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="424750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6100/3000s" start="1503700/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="430850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="850/3000s" start="1510450/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="431700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="16900/3000s" start="1514650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="448600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10600/3000s" start="1532100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="459200/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6400/3000s" start="1543900/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="465600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3850/3000s" start="1550800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="469450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4150/3000s" start="1555750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="473600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="4150/3000s" start="1560750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="477750/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2050/3000s" start="1565850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="479800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="7050/3000s" start="1569750/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="486850/3000s" ref="r2" duration="14750/3000s" start="1612850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="501600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="6850/3000s" start="1629100/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="508450/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3050/3000s" start="1636850/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="511500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="300/3000s" start="1643300/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="511800/3000s" ref="r2" duration="1900/3000s" start="1665550/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="513700/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3900/3000s" start="1668800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="517600/3000s" ref="r2" duration="10400/3000s" start="1679950/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="528000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="2500/3000s" start="1691000/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="530500/3000s" ref="r2" duration="3500/3000s" start="1693800/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>
                        <asset-clip name="1x.mp4" offset="534000/3000s" ref="r2" duration="12000/3000s" start="1697650/3000s" tcFormat="NDF"/>

                    </spine>
                </sequence>
            </project>
        </event>
    </library>
</fcpxml>'''


def _should_collect_asset(asset):
  _duration = int(asset.attrib['duration'].split('/')[0])
  return _duration >= MIN_SIZE
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
assets = root.findall('.//asset-clip')
filtered_assets = [a for a in assets if _should_collect_asset(a)]
spine = root.find('.//spine')
spine.clear()
spine.extend(filtered_assets)
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to include ~140 lines of XML that is already in the question? Now we have to scroll past all that to get to the gist of the answer.

Comment: Well.. I understand your complain. But on the other hand a working "copy and paste" solution is always good for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @balderman ElementTree based solution, here's one with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML([your xml above].encode())
for duration in doc.xpath('//asset-clip'):
    if (int(duration.xpath('./@duration')[0].split('/')[0])<1000):
        duration.getparent().remove(duration)
```